# How can I use gauge/taiko with other browser?

Tags: getgauge

I use gauge/taiko/javascript this month and want use browser in my pc.
I try to use gauge run --env="firefox" specs/ but not work.
Any sample?

Comment: Taiko only works on Chrome at the moment. Taiko uses Chrome DevTools protocol via the Chrome remote interface node js library.

Answer (score 0):

To start with did you create the environment?
https://docs.gauge.org/latest/configuration.html#creating-new-environment

You should not have to use the quotes with a single environment like this

```
 gauge run --env ci specs
```

After that did you configure the project to use the new environment?
What you are doing is loading variables so you must provide the project with the variables needed to interact with that environment.  In addition to a browser, I also need the root address of the enrivonment and specifiy whether I am in the DEV(elopment), CERT(ification), or PROD(uction) environment.

```
browserToUse = chrome
rootNgsUrl = http://(urlAddress)
envInUse = dev
```

This is then used in the DriverFactory to initialize the Driver to the proper browser

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");
Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I believe that there are examples that include an example of the DriverFactory that will initialize your browser driver and allow you to use that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Taiko is a Node.js library to automate the Chrome browser. Therefore Taiko only works with Chrome browser.

[Example](https://medium.com/@gemunulk/no-more-flaky-tests-automate-modern-web-applications-with-taiko-150421da3940)

Answer (score 0):

Open your `default.properties` and add a new line at the bottom:

`TTAIKO_BROWSER_PATH = <path to your browser executable>`

For the  Chrome Browser on a windows system this would be:

```
TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH = C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
```